# Move excel formulas programmatically

Tags: excel, move, formula

I have an app which exports data to excel sheet. The user can add some formulas to excel sheet after it has exported the data like he can do `=sum(o1:o12)` and put the results in `o13`. The user also has the option to reexport the data to the same sheet. What might happen...that more or less rows would have been exported depending on some conditions. For example....
last time there 12 rows so the user put the formula the row 13 but this time 20 rows might get exported so excel should be able to move the formula from `o13` cell to `o21` and should have updated the formula from `=sum(o1:12)` to `=sum(o1:20)`. In other case...only 5 rows might get exported from app so the formula should shift to `o6` cell and formula should have been updated to `=som(o1:o5)`.

Is there any way to ask excel to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

`LastRow = Range("O65535").End(xlUp).Row` will return the number of the last filled cell in the `O` column.

Next thing to do is:

```
Range("O" & LastRow+1).Value = "=Sum(O1:O" & LastRow & ")"
Range("O" & LastRow+1).formula = "=Sum(O1:O" & LastRow & ")" will work as well.
```

Last thing, when you use `LastRow = Range("O65535").End(xlUp).Row`, be careful if the last cell in the column `O` is the sum formula.

This should work but don't hesitate to ask questions if it doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the clue. let me ask me one more thing...here in above example we know the formula = sum(o1:o10) so we could write a statement to move formulas but what if the app is unaware of the user formulas. I know that app can ask excel about its formulas but if formula is very complex and uses a lot of columns to calculate some value then how the app would be able to use this technique to achieve what exactly i want to achieve.  Please also mind that formulas can not only be in O13 cell which does =sum(o1:o12) but it can be any formula whatsoever which uses any columns to

Comment: to calculate value and put data in any cell. May be i am asking for more but i just want to see if it is possible to do in excel. i am just wondering we can instruct excel to update the precedents of all formulas and move them upwards or downwards whenever the app exports

Comment: I don't know if excel can tell what is the formula inside the cell, so i don't know i what you want is possible

Comment: While not many sheets have more than 65535 rows with data, finding the last row will fail if they do. Try LastRow = Range("O" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row instead.

Comment: Excel sheets cannot have more than 65535 lines in version of Excel up to Excel 2003, further versions can have 1M lines. You could use activeSheet, but activeSheet might not be the sheet you expect during execution of the code, i would use a variable to the sheet, or simply hardcode the max number of lines somewhere.